# How to write/deploy "daemon like" application to glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish, daemon

I have the following problem:
I have to write an application which makes modifications on databases. I have to deploy it on Glassfish 2.
This application would not recieve any external calls, it just looks at the database let's say every 10 seconds and makes some modifications.
I shouldn't write a servlet, since they are not indended to be used for these purposes. (From the init() start a thread, which does the work for us). I read, that this is against the standard.
What do you suggest?
What kind of EE application should I write to solve this issue within the "borders" of the Java EE standard?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your task via a ServerletContextListener  class and then may be run a thread (safely via an ExecutorService) that would watch your database.   It should be similar to this.  It is done in Tomcat but should not be different on Glassfish.

http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/howto_blogs/1314-asynchronous_tasks_in_jsf_applications